# Frameworks & XIB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I'm facing a strange problem concerning a XIB file in my framework. This XIB file contains a `NSWindow`, `NSTableView` and two buttons, all of which are connected via Outlets. The TableView and Buttons work as expected, but the `NSWindow` is always `(null)`.

The window's outlet **is connected** and the **XIB is being loaded correctly**, so I'm really surprised that this doesn't work for this particular instance.

I load the XIB like this: `BOOL success = [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"SomeXIB" owner:self];`

Then I try to modify the window:

```
[window setLevel:NSModalPanelWindowLevel];
[window center];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

NSLog(@"Window: %@",window);
```

The `NSLog` statement always returns `(null)` and none of the methods above do anything, the window only shows up because `Visible At Launch` is checked and won't otherwise. (which proves that the XIB is loaded fine)

Am I missing something?

Edit:

Here's all I do to the window:

```
BOOL success = [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"BrowserPrompt" owner:self];

if (success == NO)  
{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't load XIB.");
    return NO;
}

[[self delegate] pickerWillShow:self];  

[window setLevel:NSModalPanelWindowLevel];
[window center];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly, one of the following is true:

- `self.window` is not an IBOutlet
- Your XIB's File Owner is not of the same class as `self`
- You have not connected the NSWindow in IB to the File Owner's `window` IBOutlet.
- You are setting `window` to `nil` between the load and the usage.
- You are running the window modifying code before the load code (this mistake is surprisingly common).

Override `setWindow:` so you can put in logging or a breakpoint, and make sure it's being called, and check whether it's being called with `nil` or a proper value.

Comment: Strange, because the NSTableView works fine,which is in the same XIB?